# visual studio 2010 exe closes suddenly

Tags: c#, windows

I have created an exe in visual studio 2010 using c#. It executes well in my machine and in few desktop it opens and closes immediately. Please help me in getting rid of this issue.

The user could able to execute the cmd.exe where as MyTool.exe is getting closed suddenly.

Comment: Check that they have the correct version of .Net installed.

Answer (score 1):

You need the Windows Application / System event logs from the affected machines. They'll (almost certainly) tell you which .Net exception occurred. If you bundled the PDB files with your publication, you'll get a line number too.